# windows batch file sqlcmd error

Tags: windows, batch-file, sqlcmd

So this command is failing:

```bat
@ECHO off
SET CurrentDir="%CD%"
sqlcmd -Q "exec db.dbo.table" -S servername -d db -o %CurrentDir%\output.txt
```

but this one works fine:

```bat
sqlcmd -Q "exec db.dbo.table" -S servername -d db -o C:\Users\username\Desktop\output.txt
```

The error with the first one is:

> unexpected argument, or path/name is incorrect.

Comment: Do you have a question? and what is wrong with using just one line in your batch file? `@sqlcmd -Q "exec db.dbo.table" -S servername -d db -o "output.txt"`, `@sqlcmd -Q "exec db.dbo.table" -S servername -d db -o "%CD%\output.txt"`, `@sqlcmd -Q "exec db.dbo.table" -S servername -d db -o "%__CD__%output.txt"` or possibly even `@sqlcmd -Q "exec db.dbo.table" -S servername -d db -o "%~dp0output.txt"`. If you want to set a variable first, use this notation, `SET "CurrentDir=%CD%"`.

Comment: I just wanted to make the first command work (i wanted to make the output file in the directory of the bat file). You just taught me how to do that (by not referring any path at all) ! Thanks!

Comment: By way of explanation... the reason the first one fails is that the quotes are part of the contents of the variable the way you did it. If you remove the '@ECHO off' statement from your code you will see that the quotes get expanded to (incorrectly) become "C:\Users\username\Desktop"\output.txt.  Use the syntax specified in the last line of @Compo's comment to correct.